# Poner contraseña a un fichero/archivo con Java

Tags: java

Me gustaría saber como podría implementar un código en java en el que pueda ponerle una contraseña a un fichero o carpeta para que nadie pueda acceder. Se que hay programas que hacen eso, pero me gustaría implementarlo. 
Haber si alguien sabe de algún ejemplo o algo.

Comment: Si es que no se pueda acceder a una carpeta o archivo, es cosa del sistema operativo y los permisos de acceso. Si te refieres a cifrar el contenido de un archivo, hablamos de implementar un algoritmo de cifrado. En cualquier caso la pregunta es demasiado amplia para dar una respuesta. Lee sobre algoritmos de cifrado e intenta aplicar alguno ya existente (Java tiene el paquete `javax.crypto.*` para esas labores)

Comment: @PabloLozano esa debería ser una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En java existe una librería llamada **Zip4j**

Su pagina web es: http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/index.php

Esta librería tiene un método que se llama: **setPassword(String password)**

```
/**
 * Sets the password for the zip file
 * @param password
 * @throws ZipException
 */
public void setPassword(String password) throws ZipException {
    if (zipModel == null) {
        readZipInfo();
        if (zipModel == null) {
            throw new ZipException("Zip Model is null");
        }
    }

    if (zipModel.getCentralDirectory() == null || zipModel.getCentralDirectory().getFileHeaders() == null) {
        throw new ZipException("invalid zip file");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < zipModel.getCentralDirectory().getFileHeaders().size(); i++) {
        if (zipModel.getCentralDirectory().getFileHeaders().get(i) != null) {
            if (((FileHeader)zipModel.getCentralDirectory().getFileHeaders().get(i)).isEncrypted()) {
                ((FileHeader)zipModel.getCentralDirectory().getFileHeaders().get(i)).setPassword(password);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Acá tienes mas información detallada de todas las funcionalidades:**

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.lingala.zip4j/zip4j/1.2.3/net/lingala/zip4j/core/ZipFile.java#ZipFile.setPassword%28java.lang.String%29

Solo te queda hacer pruebas y ver que te sale.
Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo!